# How to create a heartbeat using MassTransit when consuming a message from AWS SQS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, timeout, visibility, masstransit

Using MassTransit with AWS SQS (simple queue service), we would like to implement a [heartbeat](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html#changing-message-visibility-timeout), as advised in the AWS docs:

> If you don't know how long it takes to process a message, create a heartbeat for your consumer process.

This requires changing the visibility of the message from code. AWS provides the [ChangeMessageVisibility](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeMessageVisibility.html) API for this. MassTransit does not seem to support this native AWS interface. Which is still no problem by itself, as it boils down to calling a HTTP endpoint (or using the [SQSClient SDK, C#](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/SQS/MSQSChangeMessageVisibilityChangeMessageVisibilityRequest.html) in our case).

For this to work one needs the `RequestHandle`. It is part of the raw response when the AWS CLI is used to receive the message (`aws sqs receive-message --queue-url http://localhost:4566/queue/my-qeueu`).

```
{
    "MessageId": "878eb3d8-2d1e-406f-87b6-24a3d493f5a9",
    "ReceiptHandle": "878eb3d8-2d1e-406f-87b6-24a3d493f5a9#464f467d-82a9-421f-bc10-cddd63630b7d",
    ...left out for brevity
}
```

Now the message ID is known at run time when inspecting the `ConsumeContext<TMyMessage>.ReceiveContext.TransportHeaders['MessageId']`. The `RequestHandle`, however, is nowhere to be found, or so it seems.

So how can one change the visibility timeout of the message in a AWS SQS queue, consumed by a MassTransit consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a duplicate of the same question asked on [GitHub Discussions](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions/3251), the same answer would be that MassTransit automatically extends the visibility timeout until the consumer completes.

Up to the maximum of 12 hours that SQS allows.